# STM32L4 SPI Transfer complete interrupt using DMA fires only once

Tags: interrupt, stm32, spi, dma

I'm trying to send an array of 10 bytes between 2 nucleo boards (NUCLEO-L432KCU) using SPI and DMA. My goal is to develop the code for the slave board using the Low Level APIs. The master board is used simply for testing and, when everything will work, it will be replaced with the real system.

Before continuing, here are some more details about the system: The sender is configured as master. The code for the master is developed using the HAL API. The Chip Select on the master board is implemented using a GPIO.
The receiver is configured as slave with the option **Receive only slave** enabled and **Hardware NSS input**. The initialization code is generated automa**G**ically using the CubeMX tool.

With my current implementation I'm able to receive data on the slave board but only once: in practice is seems that the interrupt fires only once and I'm having hard time to figure out what I am missing!

I believe the error has something to do with clearing some interrupt flags. I went through the reference manual but I cannot see what I'm doing wrong.

Following is my code for both sender and receiver.

---

**Code for the sender**

**Note**: Concerning the sender I report only the main function since all the other code is auto-generated. Furthermore, I have checked with a logic analyzer that the code works. Please let me know if you need more details.

```
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_SPI3_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  uint8_t test[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A};
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_GPIO_Port,SPI1_CS_Pin,RESET);
  HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,test,sizeof(test),1000);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_GPIO_Port,SPI1_CS_Pin,SET);

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {

  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}
```

---

**Code for the receiver**
**Note:** The configuration of the DMA and the SPI is mostly done automatically by the CubeMX tool. The other initializations for my project are provided into the main function.

```
uint8_t aRxBuffer[10];
uint8_t received_buffer[100];
uint16_t cnt = 0;

int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_SPI3_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  // Custom configuration of DMA (after calling function MX_SPI3_INIT()
  // Configure address of the buffer for receiving data
  LL_DMA_ConfigAddresses(DMA2, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_1, LL_SPI_DMA_GetRegAddr(SPI3), (uint32_t)aRxBuffer,LL_DMA_GetDataTransferDirection(DMA2, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_1));
  // Configure data length
  LL_DMA_SetDataLength(DMA2, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_1,10);
  // Enable DMA Transfer complete interrupt
  LL_DMA_EnableIT_TC(DMA2, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_1);
  // LL_DMA_EnableIT_TE(DMA2, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_1);

  // We Want the SPI3 to receive 8-bit data
  // Therefore we trigger the RXNE interrupt when the FIFO level is greater than or equal to 1/4 (8bit)
  // See pag. 1221 of the TRM
  LL_SPI_SetRxFIFOThreshold(SPI3,LL_SPI_RX_FIFO_TH_QUARTER);
  LL_SPI_EnableDMAReq_RX(SPI3);

  // Enable SPI_3
  LL_SPI_Enable(SPI3);
  // Enable DMA_2,CHANNEL_1
  LL_DMA_EnableChannel(DMA2, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_1);

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {

  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}
```

Following is the IRQ handler (the commented code represents the various attempts to make it working!):

```
void DMA2_Channel1_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DMA2_Channel1_IRQn 0 */

    // Transfer-complete interrupt management
    if(LL_DMA_IsActiveFlag_TC1(DMA2))
    {
        //LL_DMA_ClearFlag_TC1(DMA2);
        LL_DMA_ClearFlag_GI1(DMA2);
        /* Call function Transmission complete Callback */
        DMA1_TransmitComplete_Callback();
    }
    else if(LL_DMA_IsActiveFlag_TE1(DMA2))
    {
        /* Call Error function */
        int _error = 0;
    }


      // Enable SPI_3
      //LL_SPI_Disable(SPI3);
      // Enable DMA_2,CHANNEL_1
      //LL_DMA_DisableChannel(DMA2, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_1);

      //LL_DMA_EnableIT_TC(DMA2, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_1);
      // LL_DMA_EnableIT_TE(DMA2, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_1);

      // We Want the SPI3 to receive 8-bit data
      // Therefore we trigger the RXNE interrupt when the FIFO level is greater than or equal to 1/4 (8bit)
      // See pag. 1221 of the TRM
      //LL_SPI_SetRxFIFOThreshold(SPI3,LL_SPI_RX_FIFO_TH_QUARTER);
      //LL_SPI_EnableDMAReq_RX(SPI3);

      // Enable SPI_3
      //LL_SPI_Enable(SPI3);
      // Enable DMA_2,CHANNEL_1
      LL_DMA_EnableChannel(DMA2, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_1);



    //  LL_DMA_EnableIT_TE(DMA2, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_1);

  /* USER CODE END DMA2_Channel1_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN DMA2_Channel1_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END DMA2_Channel1_IRQn 1 */
}
```

Following is the initialization for the SPI and the DMA (auto-generated):

```
/* SPI1 init function */
void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{
  LL_SPI_InitTypeDef SPI_InitStruct;

  LL_GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  /* Peripheral clock enable */
  LL_APB2_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_APB2_GRP1_PERIPH_SPI1);

  /**SPI1 GPIO Configuration  
  PA1   ------> SPI1_SCK
  PA7   ------> SPI1_MOSI 
  */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = SCLK1_to_SpW_Pin|MOSI1_to_SpW_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = LL_GPIO_MODE_ALTERNATE;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = LL_GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.OutputType = LL_GPIO_OUTPUT_PUSHPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = LL_GPIO_PULL_NO;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = LL_GPIO_AF_5;
  LL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  SPI_InitStruct.TransferDirection = LL_SPI_FULL_DUPLEX;
  SPI_InitStruct.Mode = LL_SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  SPI_InitStruct.DataWidth = LL_SPI_DATAWIDTH_4BIT;
  SPI_InitStruct.ClockPolarity = LL_SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  SPI_InitStruct.ClockPhase = LL_SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  SPI_InitStruct.NSS = LL_SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  SPI_InitStruct.BaudRate = LL_SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_DIV8;
  SPI_InitStruct.BitOrder = LL_SPI_LSB_FIRST;
  SPI_InitStruct.CRCCalculation = LL_SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  SPI_InitStruct.CRCPoly = 7;
  LL_SPI_Init(SPI1, &SPI_InitStruct);

  LL_SPI_SetStandard(SPI1, LL_SPI_PROTOCOL_MOTOROLA);

  LL_SPI_EnableNSSPulseMgt(SPI1);

}
/* SPI3 init function */
void MX_SPI3_Init(void)
{
  LL_SPI_InitTypeDef SPI_InitStruct;

  LL_GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  /* Peripheral clock enable */
  LL_APB1_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_APB1_GRP1_PERIPH_SPI3);

  /**SPI3 GPIO Configuration  
  PA4   ------> SPI3_NSS
  PB3 (JTDO-TRACESWO)   ------> SPI3_SCK
  PB5   ------> SPI3_MOSI 
  */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LL_GPIO_PIN_4;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = LL_GPIO_MODE_ALTERNATE;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = LL_GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.OutputType = LL_GPIO_OUTPUT_PUSHPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = LL_GPIO_PULL_NO;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = LL_GPIO_AF_6;
  LL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = SCLK_from_SpW_Pin|MOSI_from_SpW_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = LL_GPIO_MODE_ALTERNATE;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = LL_GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.OutputType = LL_GPIO_OUTPUT_PUSHPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = LL_GPIO_PULL_NO;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = LL_GPIO_AF_6;
  LL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* SPI3 DMA Init */

  /* SPI3_RX Init */
  LL_DMA_SetPeriphRequest(DMA2, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_1, LL_DMA_REQUEST_3);

  LL_DMA_SetDataTransferDirection(DMA2, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_1, LL_DMA_DIRECTION_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY);

  LL_DMA_SetChannelPriorityLevel(DMA2, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_1, LL_DMA_PRIORITY_LOW);

  LL_DMA_SetMode(DMA2, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_1, LL_DMA_MODE_NORMAL);

  LL_DMA_SetPeriphIncMode(DMA2, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_1, LL_DMA_PERIPH_NOINCREMENT);

  LL_DMA_SetMemoryIncMode(DMA2, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_1, LL_DMA_MEMORY_INCREMENT);

  LL_DMA_SetPeriphSize(DMA2, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_1, LL_DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE);

  LL_DMA_SetMemorySize(DMA2, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_1, LL_DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE);

  /* SPI3 interrupt Init */
  NVIC_SetPriority(SPI3_IRQn, NVIC_EncodePriority(NVIC_GetPriorityGrouping(),0, 0));
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(SPI3_IRQn);

  SPI_InitStruct.TransferDirection = LL_SPI_SIMPLEX_RX;
  SPI_InitStruct.Mode = LL_SPI_MODE_SLAVE;
  SPI_InitStruct.DataWidth = LL_SPI_DATAWIDTH_4BIT;
  SPI_InitStruct.ClockPolarity = LL_SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  SPI_InitStruct.ClockPhase = LL_SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  SPI_InitStruct.NSS = LL_SPI_NSS_HARD_INPUT;
  SPI_InitStruct.BitOrder = LL_SPI_LSB_FIRST;
  SPI_InitStruct.CRCCalculation = LL_SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  SPI_InitStruct.CRCPoly = 7;
  LL_SPI_Init(SPI3, &SPI_InitStruct);

  LL_SPI_SetStandard(SPI3, LL_SPI_PROTOCOL_MOTOROLA);

  LL_SPI_DisableNSSPulseMgt(SPI3);

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently implemented a similar system, and I hope I can help. I have a few questions, comments, which can possibly solve your problem, but it is hard to do so without being there.

- Do you know if it is the SPI or DMA that is fauly? Does an SPI interrupt occur on the slave? This would mean the DMA is faulty, and not the SPI. It is important to know exactly where the system fails.
- `LL_SPI_SetRxFIFOThreshold(SPI3,LL_SPI_RX_FIFO_TH_QUARTER);` is necessary, but should be done during the `init`
- The `TCIF` flag should be cleared (as you did) during the `IRQ`.
- You should set the SPI to trigger the DMA (I don't see it in your code) using the `SPI_CR2_RXDMAEN` register. This you should also do during the `init` if you do not know when you will receive data.
- For the same reason I think you should enable the DMA channel during the `init`, and keep it enabled.

I hope one of these comments help. If not, we will try again.

**Edit:** Good work. I am glad you got it running by solving most of the issues. With the information you provided I figured out what was the main problem with the buffer.

You set the DMA to receive 10 bytes with:

```
LL_DMA_SetDataLength(DMA2, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_1,10);
```

This sets the DMA internal counter to 10. For every byte that it receives the counter decreases by one, until it reaches zero. This is what enables it to count 10 bytes. In *normal* mode, if you want to receive another 10 bytes, then you need to send that command again. In *circular* mode this value will reset **automatically** to 10, which means that it can receive another 10 bytes.

Therefore, if you are expecting to **always** receive 10 bytes then the *cicular* mode should work just fine for you. If **not**, then you will have to use *normal* mode, and specify to the MCU how many bytes you expect (a little more complicated).

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. If I'm not wrong the LL_SPI_SetRxFIFOThreshold should be fine: according to the STM32L4 LL example projects, this function is called right after calling the LL_SPI_Init function. The SPI_CR2_RXDMAEN is enabled calling the function LL_SPI_EnableDMAReq_RX(SPI_TypeDef* SPIx), so the problem should not be there.
What I have noticed is the following: if I put a breakpoint on the LL_DMA_ClearFlag_GI1(DMA2); function, the status register (SR) has RXNE = 0x01, TXE = 0x01, OVR = 0x01 and FRLVL = 0c03. This means an Overrun error occurred and, in fact, the FIFO is full.

Comment: However, running the instruction LL_DMA_ClearFlag_GI1(DMA2); clears the OVR, RXNE and FRLVL. This is strange since I know that I'm sending exactly 10 bytes, and on the receiver side the aRxBuffer has dimension 10, so it should be fine in my opinion. I have also tried to increase the aRxBuffer to 20 (just to see) but the problem still persists.

Comment: Update: I have solved the problem about the OVR flag being set, but the main issue still remains. I have also noticed the following: if I send 10 bytes, let's say "ABCDEFGHIJ", when the LL_DMA_IsActiveFlag_TC1 is true on the IRQ routine, the Data Register contains "GH" and not "IJ" as I would expect.

Comment: I guess I have finally figured out. If I set the DMA buffer from NORMAL to CIRCULAR it works. However, I'm thinking why it doesn't work if I set it in normal mode: If I expect to receive exactly 10 bytes, after 10 bytes the buffer should reset. Is this right?

Comment: Good work! I updated my answer to explain the buffer modes, and why your code didn't receive more than one transmission. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

From the code
stm32l4xx_hal_spi.c: 55

```
      Master Receive mode restriction:
      (#) In Master unidirectional receive-only mode (MSTR =1, BIDIMODE=0, RXONLY=1) 
          or bidirectional receive mode (MSTR=1, BIDIMODE=1, BIDIOE=0), to ensure 
          that the SPI does not initiate a new transfer the following procedure has 
          to be respected:
          (##) HAL_SPI_DeInit()
          (##) HAL_SPI_Init()
```

So before you call HAL_SPI_Receive_DMA()
call HAL_SPI_DeInit and HAL_SPI_Init and it should work.

I found that if you just call

```
 HAL_DMA_DeInit(HSPI_Handle->hdmatx) ;
 HAL_DMA_Init(HSPI_Handle->hdmtx);
```

Also works and is only 70us vs 106us.